# Error found when loading /home/{username}/.profile in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I am getting this error message after every login from gnome terminal in my ubuntu 18.04 system.Please somebody help me to fix this error.

[Screenshot of error I am receiving on my end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GdWT.jpg)

Comment: It looks like your `~/.profile` file has underscores where it should have spaces - you will need to edit and correct it - or replace with a default one from the `/etc/skel` directory

Comment: yeah thanx @steeldriver you were right the problem is fixed now.tysm